# viewDidLoad not called when modifying navigation stack

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am removing all views from the navigation stack, then creating a new controller (from a storyboard) and adding it as the only controller in the stack. The problem is that viewDidLoad is never called (checked it with a breakpoint) when the new controller is instantiated. Any ideas why this is happening? Code below.

```
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
PFGridPageViewController *nc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GridPageVC"];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:nil];
NSArray *new = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nc, nil];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:new];
```

**Temporary solution**

As you can see in my discussion with Ian in the accepted answer, modifying the navigation stack is a bad idea. I've come up with a temporary solution while I work on something better. Basically I use popToRoot and pushVC and then modify the stack once to remove the VC at index 0.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
PFGridPageViewController *nc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GridPageVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nc animated:NO];
NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[controllers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllers];
```

Comment: The problem in your code is setting viewControllers to nil. There's no need to do that. If you just assign a new array to the navigation controller's viewControllers property, it works properly. I don't think you should have even seen your new view controller (did you?) because when you set viewControllers to nil, self.navigationController will become null.

Comment: You can also use setViewControllers:animated: to make it look like your pushing nc onto the stack, even though your resetting the array.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with modifying the stack, by resetting the viewControllers array, as long as you do it correctly (look at what Apple says in the reference to the method, 
setViewControllers:animated:). It's not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is only called when you access the `.view` property of a `UIViewController`. This seems like a really unconventional way of doing a `[self.navigationController pushViewController:nc animated:NO]`.

If you are sure about your implementation (I'm not), just add in this line somewhere and it will call `viewDidLoad` for you:

```
[nc view];
```

Comment: I agree the implementation is very weird but it's the best way I can find to accomplish what I need. It's only used in one place, I use traditional navigation everywhere else. Thanks for your answer, viewDidLoad is now getting called.

Comment: Any idea how to get the other life cycle methods (viewWillAppear etc.) to work? They aren't getting called either, even with your addition.

Comment: Lifecycle methods like `viewWillAppear` gets propagated to all child view controllers; I suppose you could accomplish this with `[self.navigationController addChildViewController:nc]`, but I still don't like this implementation. By using `setViewControllers:nil`, you're causing your existing stack to also not get the tear-down lifecycle events (`viewWillDisappear`, etc). Are you sure that you can't just use `popViewControllerAnimated:` and `pushViewController:animated:`?

Comment: "By using setViewControllers:nil, you're causing your existing stack to also not get the tear-down lifecycle events" I wasn't aware of that! Basically I have a nav controller with a number of view controllers. When a button is placed I need to remove all of these view controllers and replace them with a new one.

Comment: `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` followed by `pushViewController:animated:`.

Comment: Thanks. I've no idea why I went down such a weird route when that works fine.

Comment: One final issue - if I pop to root I'm still left with one vc on the stack. I'm doing a paging type of system so I'm essentially left with an old page at the beginning of the stack and the push puts me on to page 2. This is why I modified the stack directly :) Any way you can think of around it?

Comment: You cannot pop the root view controller of a `UINavigationController`. You could make this root controller a blank `UIViewController` on initial creation, though.

Comment: Yeh I was thinking of that. Guess I'm going to have to give this a little though. Thanks for your help, I'm one step closer now.